# How to see the search found using curl o wget?

Tags: wget

I need to see the searches found using curl or wget , when it find results with '301' status code.

This is my variable using curl.

```
website=$(curl -s --head -w %{http_code} https://launchpad.net/~[a-z]/+archive/pipelight -o /dev/null | sed 's#404##g') 

echo $website
301
```

**The above works, but only display if the site exists with '301' status code.**

**I want**

```
echo $website

https://launchpad.net/~mqchael/+archive/pipelight
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "effective URL" to your output.  Change `%{http_code}` to `"%{http_code} %{url_effective} "`.

From there, it's just a matter of fussing with the regular expression.  Change the *sed* string to `'s#404 [^ ]* ##g'`.  That will eliminate (assuming you don't already know) not just the 404s, but will also eat the URL that follows it.

So:

```
curl -s --head -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective} " https://launchpad.net/~[a-z]/+archive/pipelight -o /dev/null | sed 's#404 [^ ]* ##g''s#404 [^ ]* ##g'
```

will give you:

```
301 https://launchpad.net/~j/+archive/pipelight
```

You may want to replace the HTTP codes with new-lines, after that.